# Problems with dynamically generated radio Buttons (Angular *ngfor)

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to create several radio buttons with `*ngfor`.

```
<div class="gruendeAll">
<div class="gruende" *ngFor="let item of data">
  <label for="radiogrund{{item.grund}}">
    <input id="radiogrund{{item.grund}}" [value]='item.grund' value="grundValue" type="radio" name="grund" [(ngModel)]="form" class="select">
    {{item.grund}}
  </label>
</div>
</div>
```

And the buttons are supposed to be in a grid, therefore this is my .css

```
.gruende {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  align-items: center;
}

.gruende input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.gruende label {
  display: table-cell;    /* set Text in vertical center (with vertical align) */
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;     /* set Text in horizontal center */
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  background-color: #424249;
  color: white;
  width: 205px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.gruende input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #969699;
}
```

Unfortunately the buttons are positioned among themselves and not in a grid (e.g. 3x3). I tried it with 10x `<input type="radio">` and here it works. So the problem has something to do with `*ngfor` I guess.
Also I cannot select a button, I click on the button but nothing happens (the button should change the color like its mentioned in the .css)

By the way, I am getting the `data` for the radio buttons out of a database (I have a Spring Boot connection). So I want to create dynamically more buttons.

Here is where I subscribe to the `data`:

```
 this.vorgangService.getGruende().subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;

      this.grund = data.grund;

      this.size = this.data.length;
    });
```

I also have a formgroup in my .ts

```
form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group( {

  });
```

Comment: show your `radiogrund` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with either FormGroup or Reactive forms:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvpjjb

### HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="gruende">
        <div class="gruende" *ngFor="let item of data">
            <label class="gruende__label" [class.gruende__label--checked]="radio.checked" [for]="'radiogrund-'+item.grund">
            {{item.grund}}
    <input #radio  [id]="'radiogrund-'+item.grund" 
            type="radio" 
            class="select" 
            formControlName="myRadioInput" 
            [value]="item.grund">
  </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>Form value: {{ myForm.value | json }}</p>
</form>
```

### Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  data = [
    { grund: "1" },
    { grund: "2" },
    { grund: "3" },
    { grund: "4" }
  ];

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      myRadioInput: []
    });
  }
}
```

### CSS

```css
.gruende {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  align-items: center;
}

.gruende input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.gruende__label {
  display: table-cell;    /* set Text in vertical center (with vertical align) */
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;     /* set Text in horizontal center */
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  background-color: #424249;
  color: white;
  width: 205px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.gruende__label--checked {
    background-color: #969699;
}
```

## update

To add a class to the radio button thats checked you can add an angular template reference variable `<input #radio ...` and on your label toggle a class based on if it is checked or not `[class.gruende__label--checked]="radio.checked"`

Comment: I still cannot select a button. And the grid is not working either.

Comment: Oh right I see, what version of Angular are you using as Reactive Forms is what you want https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms.I'll update my anwser

Comment: I am using Angular 7

Comment: I still cannot select a button. I click on one and nothing happens

Comment: oh ok sorry, I see your issue, you can do that with angular, i have updated the answer

Comment: I made it work witch your stackblitz. I just changed some small things. I still use :checked for the css part, when the radio button is checked. But nevertheless thanks for you time and help!

Comment: Do you mind marking this question as correct so other people with similar issues know it’s worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem maybe a static property `id` and `for`, Try to use dynamic `[id]` and `[for]`. Moreover you mix other dynamic and static properties in input.

```
 <label [for]="radiogrund{{item.grund}}">
<input [id]="radiogrund{{item.grund}}"
```